# The method setTitle

Tags: java

So this is my code

```html
package me.Liam.H3k0Crew;

import org.lwjgl.util.Display;

public class H3k0Crew {
 
 public static String Client_Name = "H3k0Crew";
 public static double Client_Version = 1.0;
 
 public static final H3k0Crew H3k0Crew = new H3k0Crew();
 
 public static void StartClient(){
  Display.setTitle(Client_Name + "(rel-" + Client_Version + ")");
   }
 }
```

And it gives me a error 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the most recent version of LWJGL? I couldn't find the `Display` class in LWJGL 3. In LWJGL 2 the Display class didn't have anything related to setting titles. Your tutorial may be outdated.